# Can't refactor/rename Javascript from Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, rename

When I try to rename a variable in Javascript using Javascript Editor, it first changes all name occurences as expected, but then reverts back everything.

Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.2 (Juno),
Build id: M20130204-1200.

Restarting Eclipse or deleting and then re-importing the project didn't help.

Here is the content of .metadata/.log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui 4 10001 2013-06-12 17:21:11.586
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1679)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper.perform(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.refactoring.RenameSupport.perform(RenameSupport.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.RenameLinkedMode.doRename(RenameLinkedMode.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.RenameLinkedMode$EditorSynchronizer.left(RenameLinkedMode.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeModel.exit(LinkedModeModel.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI$4.run(LinkedModeUI.java:1193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.internalSearch(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.search(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.getOccurrences(RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameMethodProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameMethodProcessor.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.JavaRenameProcessor.checkFinalConditions(JavaRenameProcessor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring.checkAllConditions(Refactoring.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper$Operation.run(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.run(JavaScriptCore.java:3844)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Root exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.internalSearch(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.search(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.getOccurrences(RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameMethodProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameMethodProcessor.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameNonVirtualMethodProcessor.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.JavaRenameProcessor.checkFinalConditions(JavaRenameProcessor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring.checkAllConditions(Refactoring.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper$Operation.run(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.run(JavaScriptCore.java:3844)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```